# My Ajax is returning success but not updating mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

Whenever I submit my form my session[''playerPlan] always returns the plan of the user before it. So I decided to update the user's plan after submit. So far it's been going good, I've been getting the success message but ajax is not updating the database. Here's my echoed query(for user number 115):`UPDATE KingOfQuiz SET plan = '2' WHERE id = 115 LIMIT 1`. I'm not looking for SQL injections right now because this is just testing on localhost.

Form(not the issue but for id's):

```
<form action="actionSignUp.php" method="post" id="signupForm" class="signupForm">
              <h2>Signup</h2>
                <input type="hidden" name="loginActive" id="loginActive" value="0">
                <br>
            <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="username" class="col-lg-16 col-form-label">Username:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control signupInput" name="username" id="username" aria-describedby="username" autocomplete="username" autofocus required>
            </div>
            <p><span class="error"><?php echo $usernameError;?></span><p>
                </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="password" class="col-lg-16 col-form-label">Password:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input type="password" class="form-control signupInput" id="Password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" required>
              </div>
              <p><span class="error"><?php echo $passwordError;?></span><p>
            </div>
            
            <h4>Account Type <i class="far fa-question-circle info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Whenever you have all free accounts checked, payment method should be hidden, but if not then click on any paid account and then click back!" height="16px"></i></h4>
            <p>Visit <a href="pricing.php">Plan</a> for pricing details.</p>
              <div class="input-group-prepend row">
                  <input type="button" class="dropdown-item col-md-4 active dropdownI plan" value="Player: Free Account $0.00/Mo" class="FA playAccount" id="dfreePlayerAccount" name="fa">
                  <input type="button" class="dropdown-item col-md-4 dropdownI plan" value="Player: Pro Account $5.99/Mo" class="FA" id="dproPlayerAccount" name="pa">
                  <input class="dropdown-item col-md-4 dropdownI plan" value="Player: Premium Account $9.99/Mo" class="FA" id="dpremiumPlayerAccount" name="pra">
              </div>
                <br>
              <input type="radio" id="freePlayerAccount" class="free readonly" name="account" value="1" checked>
              <label for="freePlayerAccount">Player: Free Account $0.00/Mo</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="proPlayerAccount" class="paid readonly" name="account" value="2">
              <label for="proPlayerAccount">Player: Pro Account $5.99/Mo</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="premiumPlayerAccount" class="paid readonly" name="account" value="3">
              <label for="premiumPlayerAccount">Player: Premium Account $9.99/Mo</label><br>
              <hr>
                 <h5>Optional:</h5>
                 <div class="row">
                  <input type="button" class="dropdown-item col-sm-6 CA" value="Creator: Pro Account $9.99/Mo" name="pca" id="dproCreatorAccount">
                  <input type="button" class="dropdown-item col-sm-6 CA" value="Creator: Premium Account $14.99/Mo" id="dpremiumCreatorAccount" name="prca">
                  </div>
            <br>
              <input type="radio" id="creatorProAccount" class="paid creatorAccount readonly" name="creatorAccount" value="5">
              <label for="creatorProAccount">Creator: Pro Account $9.99/Mo</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="creatorPremiumAccount" class="paid creatorAccount readonly" name="creatorAccount" value="6">
              <label for="creatorPremiumAccount">Creator: Premium Account $14.99/Mo</label><br>
                <hr>
            <div class="hiddenPaymentMethod"> <h5>Payment Method</h5>
              <input type="radio" id="Paypal" name="payment" value="Paypal" class="payment">
              <label for="Paypal">Paypal</label><br>
              <input type="radio" id="creditCard" name="payment" value="CreditCard" class="payment">
              <label for="creditCard">Credit Card</label><br>
              <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="creditCardNumber" id="creditCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number">
              <input type="radio" id="debitCard" name="payment" value="DebitCard" class="payment">
          <label for="debitCard">Debit Card</label>
               <input type="text" style="display:none;" name="debitCardNumber" id="debitCardNumber" placeholder="Card Number"> 
                <br></div>
                <br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="termsAndConditions" class="conditions" name="termsandconditions" value="0">
            <label for="termsAndConditions"> I have read and agreed to the Terms and Conditions <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="far fa-question-circle questionMark"></i></span></label>
            <p id="errors"></p>
            <p id="tacError" style="color:red"></p>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="signupButton" id="signUpButton" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

My ajax (The second ajax is the updating one):

```
$("#signUpButton").click(function() { 
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "actionSignUp.php",
                        data: "username=" + $("#username").val() + "&password=" + $("#Password").val() + "&termsandconditions=" + $("#termsAndConditions").val() + "&fa=" + $("#dfreePlayerAccount").val() + "&pa=" + $("#dproPlayerAccount").val() + "&pra=" + $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").val() + "&pca=" + $("#dproCreatorAccount").val() + "&prca=" + $("#dpremiumCreatorAccount").val() + "&account=" + $(".playAccount").val() + "&loginActive=" + $("#loginActive").val()
                    }).done(function(result)  {
                            $("#errors").html(result);
                        }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        
                            alert("Error Requesting. Please Try Again Later.");
                        
                        });

                    }); 

                $(document).ready(function(){
                  $('#signupForm').on('submit' , function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var plan = $('.playAccount').val();
                    var key = "";
                    var value = "";
                    if (plan == $("#dfreePlayerAccount").val()) {
                      key = "fa";
                      value = $("#dfreePlayerAccount").val();
                    } else if (plan == $("#dproPlayerAccount").val()) {
                      key = "pa";
                      value = $("#dproPlayerAccount").val();
                    } else if (plan == $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").val()) {
                      key = "pra";
                      value = $("#dpremiumPlayerAccount").val();
                    }
                    var data = {
                      plan: plan
                    };
                    data[key] = value;
                    $.ajax({
                      method: "POST",
                      url: "ChangeUserPlan.php",
                      data: data
                    }).done(function(updated){
                        console.log(updated);
                    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         console.log("Error Requesting. Please Try Again Later.");
                    });
                  });
                });
```

Updating User PHP:

```
require('signup.php');
    $link = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "Nice Try", "Nope, Not giving it");
    
     
    if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
         
         die("Couldn't connect to the database. try again later.");
         
     } 
 
      $query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";

      if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
          
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          
    }
    $_SESSION['playerPlan'] = "1";
            if(isset($_REQUEST['fa'])) {
                $_SESSION['playerPlan'] = "1";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['pa'])) {
                $_SESSION['playerPlan'] = "2";
            }
            if(isset($_REQUEST['pra'])) {
                $_SESSION['playerPlan'] = "3";
            }
   
    $playingPlan = $_SESSION['playerPlan'];
   
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        echo $_SESSION['playerPlan'];
        $query = "UPDATE KingOfQuiz SET plan = '". $playingPlan."' WHERE id = ".$_SESSION['id']." LIMIT 1";
        mysqli_query($link, $query);
        echo $query;

    } else {
        echo "Sorry Try Again Later.";
    }
```

Comment: Huge Security issues without prepared statements. Connection should be in a separate secure folder, as well. No reason to `LIMIT` an `UPDATE`. In order to use `$_SESSION` you need to call `session_start();` before headers are sent. I would also stay away from `$_REQUEST` and just use `$_POST`. You do need to test like `if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){ /* now use the $_POST vars */ }`.

Comment: I have the file included, so I don't need session-start();

Comment: Is there anything I can do to update the session, because when I tried a simple update statement it didn't update. So is it that ajax doesn't have the data to do the function but it's having a success message in the console.

Comment: Yep, it's something in the AJAX

Comment: Oh, I put the database name instead of the table, What a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My table had the wrong name

The table that had to be updated was users.